# Discord.Message.Embed is not a constructor

Tags: discord.js

so i tried making an embed. this is the code for it

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

//example (inside of a command)

const embed = new Discord.messageEmbed()
embed.setAuthor(`Phaze Bot`)
embed.setTitle(`Commands List`)
embed.setDescription(`$kick: kicks a member \n $ban: bans a member \n $help music: displays music commands \n $help: displays the help screen`)

message.channel.send({embed});
```

*Update* so now i got that working, but the bottom line of the code sends

> Blockquote
> ReferenceError: message is not defined

i now need a fix on this if anyone can help

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in curly braces?

Comment: i was using an open source, it was just like that

Comment: i dont really know what it means yet, i started yesterday, but is there any way you could help?

Comment: And did you try removing it? Please provide more code if possible.

Comment: this was all the code i used for the embed sorry. i havent removed the curly brackets but i can if you want me to

Comment: Yes please remove the curly braces and keep me updated.

Comment: ok will do, thanks

Comment: also, you wouldnt happen to know how i can post that embed to a specific channel in my support server would you?

Comment: Please get the send function to work first, then we can look on further things.

Comment: ok. thats fine. ill update you on it

Comment: right so i got the above bit workig, it no longer says that it isnt a constructor, i just need the bottom of that block of code fixing now, its saying 
ReferenceError: message is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the function inside a `on` event:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", (message) => {
   const embed = new Discord.messageEmbed()

   embed.setAuthor(`Phaze Bot`)
   embed.setTitle(`Commands List`)
   embed.setDescription(`$kick: kicks a member \n $ban: bans a member \n $help music: displays music commands \n $help: displays the help screen`)

   message.channel.send(embed);
})
```

If you want to send the message to specific channel as you mentioned, you would want to use something like this:

```js
client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID).send(embed)
```

Comment: thanks, it has fixed that. only problem is that now it is saying: ReferenceError: client is not defined

Comment: You are right, my bad, I updated the answer. If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: or am i meant to put that client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID).send(embed) line of code in its place?

Comment: Replace message.channel.send(embed) with client.channels.cache.get(CHANNEL_ID).send(embed) to send message to specific channel (replace CHANNEL_ID with a actual id).

Comment: sorry to bother you again. it isnt sending into my bot commands channel. i have put its id in and added the bot token on the end of the code block. would you possibly be able to help me again?

Comment: It is hard to tell what is the problem now, consider opening a new question or just search on the web, there are thousands of resources!